# Get link to image stored in database in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, image

I want to get the url to image stored in database as byte array, to use this image url in other pages. My implementation is as follows:

Model

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public FileContentResult GetImageById(int id)
    {
        Image image = _imageRepository.GetImageById(int id);
        var byteArray = image.Photo;
        if (byteArray != null)
        {
            return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/jpeg");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and in View I do this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImageById", "Image", new { id = item.ProductID })" alt="@item.Name" />
```

and as a result I see image from database, but the link is: http://mypageaddress.com/Image/
I can save it to disk, but cannot share the link to this image. How can I set everything to get links to images stored in database in the following format: http://mypageaddress.com/Image/myimagetitle.jpg and store this information in the Url property of my model, so to generate the link during upload?

Comment: Do you have a custom route for your images?

Comment: No, do I have to get one? How should I define it?